# Power BI filter over 6 month and last 6 month

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I would like to create a button filter in power bi that would allow me to show the values ​​that have been active for more than 6 months and those that have been active for less than 6 months, I will explain an example:

| DATE | IMPORT | CLIENT_ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-11-01 | 55.56 | C001 |
| 2022-10-01 | 23.5 | C001 |
| 2022-09-01 | 12.6 | C002 |
| 2022-03-01 | 56.2 | C003 |
| 2022-02-01 | 45.2 | C001 |
| 2022-01-01 | 34.5 | C003 |

Then in Power Bi have a filter like this:

[image: Power Bi Filter]

So when I click on "last 6 month" in the matrix will appear:

Matrix result applied "last 6 month"

[image: Matrix result applied "last 6 month" filter]

And if I click on "over 6 month" the matrix will change the data for:
[image: Matrix result applied "over 6 month filter"]

Comment: Don't share data as JPG, but as text unless you want everyone to enter the numbers manually.

Comment: Thank u so much, I am trying to edit the post, but I have no idea :(

Answer (score 0):

Add a **calculated column** with the following expression

```
period name = 
IF (
    'Table'[DATE] < DATE( YEAR(TODAY()), MONTH(TODAY()) - 6, DAY(TODAY())),
    "over 6 month",
    "last 6 month"
)
```

to your 'Table' and use it in your slicer.

Comment: Did the answer help to solve your problem?